# Cannot display dynamic text AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, dynamic

I make a dynamic text named `"abc"`. I want to displaying a text like `"testing"` but I didn't get anything. It's really blank.

This is my script :

```
abc.text = "testing";
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the script you posted. Need more information.

Comment: This isn't a script. It's only a variable declaration.

Comment: It's a very short script. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your current experience in programming, but you'll need to create a new instance of the `TextField` class and add that instance into the display field using the `addChild()` function. All instances of the `TextField` class are `dynamic` by default

First you need to create the instance of `TextField` and set its text:

```
//Creates a new instance of the TextField class with the name newText
var newText:TextField = new TextField();

//Sets the text of the newText
newText.text = "testing";
```

In order to change certain things such as font size or aligning you **also** need to create an instance of the TextFormat class. You'll need to set the new text's format to the format you created and adjusted to your liking:

```
//Creates a new instance of the TextFormat class
var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

//Scales the format to the font size 24
newFormat.size = 24;

//Sets the newText's format to the format you created
newText.defaultTextFormat = newFormat;
```

Lastly in order to view the text on the display field you must simply use the `addChild()` function:

```
//Adds the newText TextField to the stage so you can see it
stage.addChild(newText);
```

So here's the finished code:

```
//Creates a new instance of the TextField class
var newText:TextField = new TextField();

//Creates a new instance of the TextFormat class
var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

//Scales the text to the font size 24
newFormat.size = 24;

//Sets the newText object's format to the format you created
newText.defaultTextFormat = newFormat;

//Sets the newText object's text to "testing"
newText.text = "testing";

//Adds the newText TextField to the stage so you can see it
stage.addChild(newText);
```

If you want you can look at both the [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) and [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html) references to see all else you can adjust (like color, anti-alias type and such, but I won't cover all of that).

There are some slight problems with this code though. You're better off creating a custom class (I call mine Text) that suits your needs, and you'll also need to **embed** your text so a computer that doesn't support the text you're using in your program will be able to see it anyway. There's a handy tutorial but I can't link more than 2 things at a time unfortunately, but if you just search "AS3: Text Fields and Formats - Republic of Code" it should be the first search result.

Answer (score 0):

You should **embedde** font. And it should work.
If you are using Flash Professional goto to menu tab **Text -> Font Embedding**
then a windows will be oppend. You should select your font, give it a name and after that in **Character Range** you can select **all** now hit **ok** 
and **VOILA....... :)**
Hope this helps...